# benefit of using template vs function and how to deduce type in template

Tags: c++, templates

I've read quite a few posts on deducing variable type, both using auto and without.  I think I am down to two questions.

Lets take a simple range function as an example.  I can make it a template and call it:

```
template <class T, T min, T max> bool inRange(T value) {
   return min <= value && value <= max;
}

bool bbb = inRange<int, 5, 10>(7);
```

or I can do:

```
template <class T> bool inRange(T min, T max, T value) {
    return min <= value && value <= max;
}

bool bbb = inRange(5, 10, 7);
```

---

**Questions**:

1. Is there a way (short of creating multiple templates 1 each for short, int, long, double, etc) that the type can be deduced such that the template can be called with `inRange<min, max>(value)`
2. Is there any advantage of `inRange<min, max>(value)` as to `inRange(min, max, value)`

Comment: `inRange<min, max>(value)` only works if `min`/`max` are constants.

Comment: There have been some proposals to allow deduction of types of non-type template parameters, but they're not ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not at the moment. There is a proposal to add this to a future version of C++: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4469.html
2. The first method `inRange<T, min, max>(value)` is rather awkward since we don't have the aforementioned proposal implemented yet and can't write `inRange<min, max>(value)`. If min and max are not known at compile time, the second method `inRange(min, max, value)` is your only option anyway. An inline function of the second kind should be just as efficient as the first kind so there is rarely any advantage.

Comment: In the unlikely event that `min > max`, the compiler can constant-fold the first example, but not the second.  However, since that has to be known at *compile time*, it probably wouldn't happen unless you have a bug of some kind.

Comment: @Kevin `min > max` is a perfectly normal way to specify an empty interval, and an empty interval is a perfectly normal way to terminate a (compile-time) recursive computation based on progressive refinement of intervals...

Comment: Fair enough, but if you're doing template meta-programming, you probably already know which example you need.

Comment: nm, Kevin.  You highlighted one thing that I missed entirely.  With inRange<min,max>(value) construct min and max must be known at compile time.   While this may work for one use case (db field range checks), it wouldn't work for my 2nd case - tolerance checking (is value in range of N +/- tolerance, with value and N being variables)